# Will Ubuntu OneConf be avaible in 11.04?

Tags: ubuntu-one, 11.04, software-center, oneconf

Will [[image]OneConf](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneConfdefinitely) be in the next release? (Integrated into Ubuntu Software Center, I mean)
Because the  [[image]Launchpad blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-maverick-oneconf) whiteboard reads:

> POSTPONE default integration into ubuntu because of synchronization in desktopcouch is failing for a lot of users. Prefer to delay one cycle to let ubuntuone guys working on that and having a sweet OneConf into Natty!

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, probably not. Right now even desktopcouch (which OneConf uses) isn't on the CD, and as far as I'm aware no further work has been done on OneConf in quite a while: the last commit to the project was in October 2010, so it's not looking good.

Nevertheless, there is still hope; you can keep track of the state of things better if you [subscribe](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-oneconf/+subscribe) to [the natty blueprint that revisits the issue](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-oneconf).

Comment: Not quite true. Didier, the author of OneConf, is still planning on working on it in this cycle.

Comment: That's why there's still hope :)